# How can I have React Native navigation load component from another file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to learn React Native navigation. This is my App.js, and it works fine, as expected:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

class App extends Component {

  HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={this.HomeScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default App;
```

Here I have defined `HomeScreen` in the App.js file itself. But what if I wanted to define it as a standalone component in another file (say HomeScreen.js), like so -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

How would I import and use that `HomeScreen` in App.js? I have tried `import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen'` and `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />` but that gives me an error saying that it's not a component. I know this is a simple, basic question, but so far I've not been able to find an answer anywhere. Is there a different navigation library I should be using to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. What I was trying to do is give the component value JSX style, like `component={<HomeScreen />}` but it should just be `component={HomeScreen}`.